# How to remove spaces between the custom UICollectionCell in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new to **`UICollectionView`** and **`UICollectionViewCell`**. Newly working on StoryBoard I have created `UICollectionView` and Customized `UICollectionViewCell`. The problem is whenever am loading the cells/rows in the collectionview finding a gap/space between two rows. I have set **"0" value for minSpace (both lines and space b/w cells)**.
Still am getting space between two cells.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: make cells bigger. the space will become 0.

Comment: I just want to support all screen sizes if increase the size of the cell it is fine in the 6+ iphone but,  in the other devices it is becoming single row view. any solutions pls.

Comment: Calculate cell size width with [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width (screen width).

Comment: If set the cell width 160 it is looking good in 5S simulator. If run the app in 6 and 6 plus simulators it showing too much gap b/w two cells. Can you pls help me? Thanks.

Comment: don't set it direct 160. set it like that. ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2 - 40) this is 160 in 5s.

Comment: Yes thank you for the suggestion. I will try it and let u know. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66456/discussion-between-yuvaraj-m-and-yusuf-terzi).